# Intuitive way of knowing why pivot positions matter?

Tags: matrices

In my LinAlge class we've learned that for the linear combinations of the columns of a matrix to be linearly independent that there must be a pivot position in each row. While I can memorize that fact I cant understand why that is the case. Can someone explain the importance of pivot positions (doesn't have to just be about span or linear independence) because I can't grast it intuitively.

Comment: who started top call them pivot positions ?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot positions (or pivot columns) are important for various reasons. One of the most fundamental reasons to why they are important is because they tell you whether your system of linear equations has no solution, exactly one solution, or infinitely many solutions.

For example, consider the system: $\\$

$x_{1} - x_{2} + 2x_{3}$ = 0 $\\$

$2x_{1} - x_{2} + x_{3}$ = 0 $\\$

$x_{1} - x_{2} + 2x_{3}$ = 0 $\\$

Suppose we wanted to find the solutions for $x_{1} , x_{2} , x_{3}$ such that Ax = 0.
Throwing this system into an augmented matrix [A|0] and row reducing produces: $\\$

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 1 & 0           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & -1 & 0         \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0          \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix} $\\$

Notice that we only have two pivot columns. However, we have a system of 3 equations and 3 unknowns. What does this tell us? It tells us that there are infinite solutions to this system of linear equations. However, if we had a pivot in each column where n = r, then we know for a fact that the only solution to our system is the trivial one. Although this illustration may seem trivial, I think it will give you a better idea of why pivot columns are important and what they tell us about the solutions to a system of linear equations.

Comment: Why is it that their are infinite solutions if there are only 2 pivots?

Comment: @tokola Well, let's take a look at our reduced system. Looking at our matrix. We have $x_{1}$ = -1, $x_{2}$ = 1, and $x_{3}$ = 0. $x_{3}$ can be anything. No matter what value we set it to $0x_{3}$ times anything will equal zero. This is known as a free variable. Since $x_{3}$ can be anything the system will have infinite solutions. However if $x_{3}$ was a 1 and every entry above it was a zero, then our system would only have one solution. Namely, $x_{1}$ = 0, $x_{2}$ = 0, and $x_{3}$ = 0.